# Is it possible to create a transparent UIButton with only border and title shown

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

Actually the question is simple. I don't know what to add to the title of my question. I need to have button which has border and title and nothing else. The rest is transparent and background of my view is seen through the button. I have googled for it a lot and found nothing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the button of type UIButtonTypeCustom and add a border to its CALayer.

```
[[myButton layer] setCornerRadius:10];
[[myButton layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:2];
```

you need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to use the layer's methods.

*EDIT (Answer to comments)*

If you created the button in Interface Builder and connected to the proper outlet, then you shouldn't create a new button in code, which is what you're doing with

```
backArrowButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
```

When you added the button in Interface Builder and connected it to the outlet, you already created it there, so just make sure that in IB it's set to Custom, and just set the layers properties in code like shown above.

Comment: It doesn't work. Nothing has changed. I did just like you said.   backArrowButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    [[backArrowButton layer] setCornerRadius:10];  
    [[backArrowButton layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [[backArrowButton layer] setBorderWidth:2];
and i imported QuartzCore but all in vain

Comment: did you set the frame of the button? does the button work, even if you can't see it?

Comment: no, i didn't set any frame. Should i? The button works fine. Let me tell you EVERYTHING i did. I just put the button on the view in xib file, then created an outlet backArrowButton, make it property, synthesysed it, connected it to the button in xib file by dragging and wrote the four lines of code which is above in the viewDidLoad method. Also i imported <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>. That's all. The button just remains an ordinary button. I see no changes. What did i miss?

Comment: see my edit to the answer, it explains what you're doing wrong.

Comment: God bless you, buddy. You've helped me a lot

Comment: no problem, that's what StackOverflow is for :) You can mark the answer as "accepted" if it helped you, so people know the problem is solved (and I get my reputation points :D )

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just make your graphic completely transparent with the border you want.  Then:

```
UIButton* button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR-IMAGE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
...
```